# Async Javascript: Trying to make AJAX API calls multiple times at interval?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

So I have a form, user searches a query.

**Trying to do:**

I make API calls consistently. The first query is entered by user, then the program makes new queries  based on Entity Analysis, and makes API calls itself - over and over.

> Issue: The results are the same, which means the code is making the
>   API calls based on the initial query over and over, instead of making
>   new queries from API results.

**Result in Console:**

```
queries length is zero...
Iterating...  undefined
On Queue Searches #1:  []
query length is zero
POST / 200 15.747 ms - -
 etc. etc. etc.
```

### code

Pushing the query entered by user into array, sending it to `onQueueSearch` to make API calls at a set interval.

```
// Global Queries
const queries = new Array();
let counter = 0; // Just to keep track

    router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
        // Assign first query
        queries.push(req.body.searchTerm);
        // Invoke the async iterator
        const results = await queryIterator(queries);
        res.send(results);
       });
```

*This function might be the problem?*
For each query in the array, do pass it to sentimentAnalyze which calls API's, this function is suppose to make calls to API consistently at set interval. ***(Note: New queries are added to queries array in the API calls.)***

```
async function onQueueSearch() {

      if(queries.length === 0 ) {
        console.log("queries length is zero...");
        return; // return something if empty
      }
      // This will extract the next in queue and remove it from queries    
      return await sentimentAnalyze(queries.pop); 
  }

// Define functions for Async Iterator -----
async function* queryGenerator() {
  while (true) {
      yield await onQueueSearch(queries.pop());
  }
}

async function queryIterator(queries) {
  for await (const result of queryGenerator()) {
      console.log('Iterating... ', result);
      console.log(`On Queue Searches #${++counter}: `, queries);
      if (!queries.length) {
          console.log("query length is zero");
          return result;
      }
  }
}
```

API calls function - Return a set of twitter results, then google api results - this async function try's to wait for returned promises/result
from twitter google api and returns

```
async function sentimentAnalyze(searchValue) {
  try {
     const tweetDocumentObject = await searchTwitter(searchValue);
     const sentimentResults = await googleSentimentAnalyze(tweetDocumentObject); 
     const entitiesResults = await googleEntityAnalyze(tweetDocumentObject);
     return {sentimentResults, entitiesResults};
 } catch(err) {
     console.log('sentimentAnalyze Error: ', err);
 }   
}
```

This function is where new queries are ADDED from entity analysis.

```
   function googleEntityAnalyze(document) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Detects entities in the document
    googleClient
    .analyzeEntities({document: document})
    .then(results => {
      const entities = results[0].entities;

      queries.unshift(req.body.searchTerm);
      entities.forEach(entity => {
          queries.unshift(entity.name);
            // console.log("Entitiy name: " +entity.name);
        // console.log(` - Type: ${entity.type} `);
        resolve({ entity  });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ENTITY ERROR:', err);
    });

  });
}
```

Comment: `await setInterval` doesn't make any sense. `setInterval` returns a number, not a `Promise`.

Comment: I had a feeling, but I don't know how to approach the issue and use setInterval method to achieve the result of multiple calls to API. Can you please demonstrate an example? New to JS @CertainPerformance

Comment: forget that .. .awaiting `setInterval` makes no sense even if it did return a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok, how should I approach it then ?

Comment: differently - I can't tell what you want your code to do `make AJAX API calls multiple times after interval?` doesn't really explain it, and the rest of your question is a lot of "I think this is the problem" ... but it's unclear (to me) what you want your code to actually do

Comment: Basically - I want to call sentimentAnalyze() over and over again after POST request is made  on the page - can we chat? @JaromandaX

Comment: `over and over again` forever? or until some condition is met? it's not clear, because you have the call in an odd while loop that sets `query.length = 0` - so the `while (query.length > 0)` makes no sense since you'll only ever run the while loop once - so, no reason for the while loop at all

Comment: and if the code is supposed to run sentimentAnalyze forever, then `results = await onQueueSearch();` makes no sense, since you'll never stop running sentimentAnalyze

Comment: I have a start button that will "Start" analyzing, similiarly I'll be adding a stop button which will "stop" analyzing - i.e. stop making calls to api. After the first query the api call returns results which are then queried themselves (added in queries array) -

Comment: @JaromandaX Hey, I've made changes to the approach based on your comment. Progressed, the isssue now is its making calls on the same query over and over and not the new queries from the returning API call. Can you please take a look?

Comment: This should work, at least it works in browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there's a couple of issues with your code, but easy to fix if you're carefull, I'll guide you through them.

**First of:**

You're **pushing** to queue always, this is the root cause of you getting the same data in queue:

```
queries.push(req.body.searchTerm); // searchTerm being '1'
... // Do more logic until googleEntityAnalyze
  entities.forEach(entity => {
    queries.push(entity.name);
    resolve({ entity  });
  });
 // Assume entities as [2, 3]
```

Now you have your queue as `[1,2,3]`, being 1 as the first argument.
Then you redo the query logic from:

```
async function onQueueSearch() {

  for(i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
    return await sentimentAnalyze(queries[i]);
     // queries[i].splice(i, 1);
  } 

  if(queries.length === 0 ) {
    console.log("queries length is zero...");
  }

}
```

The  return on the for loop will break the loop and return the first execution, which will be `queries[0] === 1`, your first argument.

So, to resolve this, keep the array in first-in-first-out, using:

```
queries.unshift(req.body.searchTerm);
entities.forEach(entity => {
    queries.unshift(entity.name);
    resolve({ entity  });
});
```

This will keep your queries in order as they arrive [3,2,1], instead of [1,2,3], now you can extract your query using `queries.pop()` instead.

```
queries.unshift(4); // where queries was [3,2,1], will be [4,3,2,1]
queries.pop(); // 1
```

*Change the sentiment analyze to:*

```
 async function onQueueSearch(){

      if(queries.length === 0 ) {
        console.log("queries length is zero...");
        return; // Return something if empty!
      }
      return await sentimentAnalyze(queries.pop());
      // This will extract the next in queue and remove it from queries    
  }
```

**Secondly, your re-call logic**

You're using an iterval to continuously recall the query, the problem with this:

```
setInterval(async function() { 
    results = await onQueueSearch(); 
  }, 3000);
```

Is that you need to *"estimate"* the time the query will take to finish before re-executing. With the query unshift and pop above you'll make this work, however, you need a more elegant solution.

**With NodeJS version < 10+:**

recursion will be useful, here's a small sample of what you're doing in a simple manner:

```
const queries = [1];
let counter = 0; // Just to keep track
async function reRunQueries(){
    counter++;
    console.log(`queries #${counter}: `, queries);
    results = await onQueueSearch();
    console.log('Results: ', results);
    if(!!queries.length){
        return await reRunQueries();
    }else{
        return results;
    }
}

async function onQueueSearch(){
    return await longQuery(queries.pop()); 
}

async function longQuery(param){
   if(param === 6){
       // Use this as stop signal!
       return param;
   }else{
       queries.unshift(++param);
       return param;
   }
}

const RES = reRunQueries();
RES.then(result => {
    console.log('RES: ', result);
})
```

It's important to know your stop signal for recursion, otherwise it will never end.

**With NodeJS > 10+**

Use a Iterable Generator:

```
const queries = [];
let counter = 0; // Just to keep track


// EMULATE EXPRESS JS call ========================
const req = { body: { searchTerm: 1 } };
const res = {send: (val) => console.log('RECEIVED: ', val)};

const router = {
    post: (route, callback) => callback(req, res)
}

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    // Assign first query
    queries.push(req.body.searchTerm);
    // Invoke the async iterator
    const results = await queryIterator(queries);
    res.send(results);
});
// The Above is for nodeJS direct testing only, 
// > you can plug it into your own router.post declaration "as is"

// -----------------------------------------
// Define functions for Async Iterator -----

async function* queryGenerator() {
    while (true) {
        yield await onQueueSearch(queries.pop());
    }
}

async function queryIterator(queries) {
    for await (const result of queryGenerator()) {
        console.log('Iterating... ', result);
        console.log(`On Queue Searches #${++counter}: `, queries);
        if (!queries.length) {
            return result;
        }
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Emulate your current async requests using queries array ----

async function onQueueSearch(param) {
    return await longQuery(param);
}

async function longQuery(param) {
    if (param === 6) {
        // Use this as stop signal!
        return Promise.resolve(param);
    } else {
        queries.unshift(++param);
        return Promise.resolve(param);
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
/*
Iterating...  2
On Queue Searches #1:  [ 2 ]
Iterating...  3
On Queue Searches #2:  [ 3 ]
Iterating...  4
On Queue Searches #3:  [ 4 ]
Iterating...  5
On Queue Searches #4:  [ 5 ]
Iterating...  6
On Queue Searches #5:  [ 6 ]
Iterating...  6
On Queue Searches #6:  []
RECEIVED:  6
*/
```

Comment: This such a great answer! I've learned a lot. Followed your steps, but its not displaying results in console, instead stuck at: POST / 200 15.747 ms - -... I've updated the question with your code, using node v10.11.0, can you PLEASE tell me if I missed a step? Thank you! I want to accept this answer!

Comment: Notice that the output log you have is: `queries length is zero... Iterating...  undefined`.  Which is caused by `onQueueSearch() { if(queries.length === 0 ) {  console.log("queries length is zero..."); return; } `  as the first statement, which is returning void *(undefined)*. Try removing that block, as the queries.length test for no more elements is now delegated to **the for loop inside `queryIterator(){...}`**, try that and let me know what you get :)

Comment: Okay, the error now is 'req' is undefined, which makes sense as       queries.unshift(req.body.searchTerm) is in googleEntityAnalyze()... do we need this here or i made a mistake? Appreciate your time

Comment: This is what function looks now: 
async function onQueueSearch() {
      // This will extract the next in queue and remove it from queries    
      return await sentimentAnalyze(queries.pop); 
  }

Comment: Results: POST / - - ms - -, POST / - - ms - - etc.

Comment: Check that you need to execute `queries.pop()`  instead of `return await sentimentAnalyze(queries.pop); ` without the execution parenthesis

Comment: And if you're passing `yield await onQueueSearch(queries.pop());` to `onQueueSearch(...)` change the `onQueueSearch()` function to receive this parameter: `async function onQueueSearch(param) { ... return await sentimentAnalyze(param); }` **Otherwise, you'd be removing two items on same call** :)

Comment: And yes, remove the `queries.unshift(req.body.searchTerm)` inside `googleEntityAnalyze(document)`

Comment: Also, please `console.log`  the param inside `async function onQueueSearch(param){console.log('param: ', param); return await sentimentAnalyze(param);}` so you know what you're requesting for the subsequent calls

Comment: You're awesome! It works, however in googleEntityAnalyze() i've had to change the arguement "req.body.searhTerm" in queries.unshift(req.body.searchTerm);  to a global variable which is set to the req.body.searchTerm in post()... It works so hopefully its not a big deal, thank you!